# Text Writer is already closed in a Delay Timer "Tick" Event

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to use a delay timer on a windows form.  I want to avoid Thread.Sleep as I want the controls to be active during the delays.  Right now I have a button that starts the code on click.  It opens a stream and writes the title line in a csv.  I then delegate the timer tick to have an if the check box is checked, it'll stop the timer, but otherwise it writes a new line.  After that, the timer is started.  The writer isn't closed until after the timer executes.  So, something like,

```
FileStream myData = File.OpenWrite("myfile.csv");
TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myData);
myWriter.Write("Titles,Go,Here\n");
int x = 0;
delayTimer.Tick+=
delegate
{
    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
        delayTimer.Stop();
    }
    myWriter.Write(x+"stuff\n");
    x++;
};
delayTimer.Start();
myWriter.Close();
```

However, whenever I try to execute, it freezes after the button press and Visual Studio informs me that the StreamWriter is closed.  I'm not really sure how to fix this, as I thought the code would execute the timer before proceeding unless I just don't understand how it's executing the timer.

Comment: try Using(mywriter.write("title etcetc);? [using and streamwriters in c#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to notice that you close the Stream after the dlay starts, so when Tick occurs the Stream is closed. Try to close the Stream inside the anonymous delegate when the job for the Stream is done.

Excuse my bad English. I hope I helped you.

Comment: I actually figured that out a few minutes after posting the question (after trying for hours to figure it out).